# Where-Object multiple conditions not working

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I am trying to get all the running builds (in progress) + with a template parameter in a specific definition. I am using Powershell@2 task in Azure DevOps to accomplish this but multiple conditions are not running using Where-Object. Below is the code:

```
$token = "123"
$organization = "foo"
$project = "abc"

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$ThisBuildDefinitionID = "8430"
[int]$ThisBuildID = "1571327"


$GET_BUILDS_BY_DEFINITION_URL = "https://azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/build/builds?api-version=6.0&definitions=$ThisBuildDefinitionID"

do
{
    $GET_BUILDS_BY_DEFINITION_RESPONSE = ""
    try
    {
      $GET_BUILDS_BY_DEFINITION_RESPONSE = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $GET_BUILDS_BY_DEFINITION_URL `
                                  -Method GET `
                                  -ContentType "application/json" `
                                  -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
    }
    catch
    {
      continue
    }
    
    Write-Host $GET_BUILDS_BY_DEFINITION_RESPONSE.value
    
    [array]$runningBuilds = $GET_BUILDS_BY_DEFINITION_RESPONSE.value | Where-Object {"status" -eq "inProgress" -and "templateParameters.param1" -eq "myparam"}

    Write-Host "running builds count: " $runningBuilds.count
    if ($runningBuilds.count -gt 0) {
      [int]$currentRunningBuild = ($runningBuilds | Sort-Object -Property "Id")[0].Id
    }

    Write-Host "This Build ID: " $ThisBuildID
    Write-Host "Currently Running Build ID: " $currentRunningBuild
    Write-Host "Waiting..." 
    Write-Output ""
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
}
while($ThisBuildID -ne $currentRunningBuild)

Write-Host "Waiting Complete."
Write-Host "Starting Build: " $ThisBuildID
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
```

`Where-Object {"status" -eq "inProgress" -and "templateParameters.param1" -eq "myparam"}` is the part where I am having issues as to what would be condition to get this running fine.

When I use only one single condition like `Where-Object "status" -eq "inProgress"`, it works fine and gets me the builds in progress but I want to also include a template parameter condition

Can someone assist me what I am doing wrong?

PS: Credit to [Devin Lambert's script](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/prevent-parallel-execution-of-the-same-build-defin/365730#T-N859271) in the visualstudio developer community.

Comment: I looked up the documentation of this API and I'm surprised it's working at all as I don't see a "value" property on the Build class which is returned by this API. But aside from that, if you are trying to apply a filter on a child property, then you could use something like this `? status -eq "inProgress" | ? { $_.templateParameters.param1 -eq "myparam"}`, you could do it all in one, but its just my preference to separate out when it won't make much of a performance impact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `Where-Object { "status" -eq "inProgress" -and "templateParameters.param1" -eq "myparam" }`

You're comparing (distinct) *string literals* to each other, whereas you presumably mean to compare *property values* to string literals.

You need the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) to refer to the pipeline input object at hand inside a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`), which allows you to access its properties:

```sh
Where-Object { 
  $_.status -eq "inProgress" -and $_.templateParameters.param1 -eq "myparam" 
}
```

---

Note that [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) (and also [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object)) alternatively supports [*simplified syntax*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Simplified_Syntax), where you don't need a script block and where the use of `$_` is *implied*, but this syntax is limited to:

- a *single* conditional
- *non-nested* property access.

Therefore, its use is *not* an option in your case.

Only the *first* `-eq` comparison, with its access to the *immediate* `status` property only could be expressed in simple syntax (as you show in your question):

```sh
# Equivalent of:
#    Where-Object { $_.status -eq 'inProgress' }
# 'status' binds positionally to the -Property parameter.
Where-Object status -eq 'inProgress'
```

By contrast, the *nested* property access would *not* work:

```sh
# !! Does NOT work as intended.
Where-Object templateParameters.param1 -eq 'myparam'
```

The reason is that `templateParameters.param1`, which positionally binds to the `-Property` parameter, is *as a whole* interpreted as the name of a *single* property.

While *chaining* multiple *simple-syntax* `Where-Object` calls may be worth it for syntactic convenience, in your case you'd have to chain a simple-syntax with a regular-syntax call, in which case you may as well stick with your original, single regular-syntax approach.